# Databases Removing a Single Element SDK Error (Multiple WHEREs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, sdk

I am trying to remove a single element from my database using an SDK. I keep getting the following error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/Users/jasonsilla/Desktop/Code/Python/Book_GUI_Program/main.py", line 25, in remove_from_list
if booksSDK.delete_book(book):
File "/Users/jasonsilla/Desktop/Code/Python/Book_GUI_Program/booksSDK.py", line 52, in delete_book
c.execute("DELETE FROM books WHERE title=?, pages=?", (book.title, book.pages))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

The code for the SDK to remove an element is as follows:

```
def delete_book(book):
    c = cursor()
    with c.connection:
        c.execute("DELETE FROM books WHERE title=?, pages=?", (book.title, book.pages))
    row_count = c.rowcount
    c.connection.close()
    return row_count
```

My question is why am I getting this error. I don't understand this, so if anyone can please help me, I believe that either the error in the code is in the:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM books WHERE title=?, (<-) pages=?", (book.title, (<- or here) book.pages))
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the 1st arrow:

```
title=?, (<- here) pages=?
```

Instead of the comma, you want to put AND. This eliminates the error. Hopefully I helped!!!